# I got outOfMemory exception what is the cause?

Tags: java, android

im trying to load some images 320× 199 in a listview and resize it for that i use the method below and after using my app and exiting it ,if i reopen it again it crashes.

```
12-30 06:03:46.249 6664 6664 E     AndroidRuntime com.WasafatPizza              FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 06:03:46.249 6664 6664 E     AndroidRuntime com.WasafatPizza              Process: com.WasafatPizza, PID: 6664
12-30 06:03:46.249 6664 6664 E     AndroidRuntime com.WasafatPizza              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-30 06:03:46.249 6664 6664 E     AndroidRuntime com.WasafatPizza              at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
12-30 06:03:46.249 6664 6664 E     AndroidRuntime com.WasafatPizza              at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
12-30 06:03:46.249 6664 6664 E     AndroidRuntime com.WasafatPizza              at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
12-30 06:03:46.249 6664 6664 E     AndroidRuntime com.WasafatPizza              at com.startapp.android.publish.ads.splash.d.b(StartAppSDK:69)



public void generatecontent(String X){
    DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
    Cursor res = mDBHlpr.getAllData(X);
    int id;
    Drawable d;
    Bitmap newBitmap;
    recipe = new String[res.getCount()];
    ingredients = new String[res.getCount()];
    steps = new String[res.getCount()];
    images = new int[res.getCount()];
    bitmaps = new BitmapDrawable[res.getCount()];
    res.moveToFirst();
    for (int j =0;j<res.getCount();j++){
        recipe[j] = res.getString(2);
        ingredients[j] = res.getString(3);
        steps[j] = res.getString(4);
        id = getResources().getIdentifier(res.getString(5), "drawable", getPackageName());
        images[j] = id;
        d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
        newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),id),d.getIntrinsicWidth()/3,d.getIntrinsicHeight()/3,false);
        bitmaps[j] = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),newBitmap);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), recipe, bitmaps);
    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    res.close();
}
```

Comment: Looks like your app runs out of memory. You could take a look at the profiler in android studio to see how many memory the app uses and which and how many objects you've got. By doing this you can maybe find a potential memory leak

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: this is not the problem it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Because `res.moveToNext()` is in a `for`, it causes your app ran out of memory.

The simplest way to loop through a `Cursor` in Android is this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(...);
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { <--- Check if cursor has next item, then move to it
        // do something here
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close(); <---- close the cursor
}
```